# How to start when building a realtime networked game for iOS using sockets?

Tags: ios, sockets, node.js

Always wanted to build a realtime and networked game for iOS, started today. Have been searching a lot on the internets about the best technical approach, I'm finding a lot but I'm missing pointers on where to start.

Here are my thoughts. It seems a socket connection over UDP is a good choice, since it's low latency and I don't really care whether packets arrive (as long as a new one does sometime). That rules out http, but what do you need that for anyway ;-). I've been reading about Nodejs and socket.io, are those good choices? I want it to be as low-level as possible, with keeping the pro's of a neat programming language and wide support for say, databases. And of course, something that mingles well with iOS (be it ordinary NSStreams or a higher-level library) is a must too.

Any pointers, advice or considerations are greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Reinder

Comment: I can't give you any recommendations for your connections with iOS clients, more than that you can build UDP servers with node. Socket.io is a wrapper for WebSockets, Flash sockets, long polling and other solutions on top of the HTTP protocol, so that's probably not what you want. There is [pretty good database support](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-database) in the node ecosystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to look into CFSocket on the iOS side. And node.js has great built-in UDP server support, so you can use it for that side natively.

Here's a really simple, possibly slightly outdated (but still good) example of CFSocket usage for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UDPEcho/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009660-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

And here's a great simple example of Dgram/UDP usage in node: http://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/archive/2011/3/Writing_A_UDP_Server_Using_Node_js.shtml

Comment: Thanks! That really looks like a good, basic, low-level example.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, [GCDAsyncSockets](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/) are really easy to use, and the wiki page for them is very helpful